# Increase the List View performance

Tags: android, listview, scroll, adapter

I have a list view with around 15 items in it.

Now in the getView():

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     //blah blah blah
     File file = new File(context.getDir("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE), fileName);
```

}

So now the problem was when i scroll the list view its smooth and when i perform some operation by selecting that item in the next activities and store it and when i come back to the list view screen, at that time when we try to scroll the scroll is not smooth, then i came to know that its because of this line:

```
File file = new File(context.getDir("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE), fileName); // accessing stored values
```

which i am calling again and again , so how can i optmize this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnScrollListener` to listen whether listview is scrolling or not and you can determine whether or not to perform operation.

Answer (score 0):

You should tell us why you're loading that data and for which purpose. Is it to display some data in the listview item? If so, preload everything before setting your list adapter, passing the data in the constructor.

Comment: yes exactly how to preload that data before the list view is displayed, i have specific values for each item , how to do it?

Comment: Check here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews

You can pass your data in the constructor of your custom adapter, so the listview already has the data. It looks like you have few entries and static, so you can go with this way.